# Problemas com Mensagem Dialog no evento Key Down

Tags: c#, dialog

Eu coloquei um evento `KeyDown` em um campo `TextBox` para quando o usuário pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>, deverá acontecer alguma ação.

Nessa ação, pedi para que apareça uma mensagem `Dialog`, mas o problema é que se o usuário pressionar duas vezes rápido a tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a mensagem irá aparecer duas vezes na tela e isso fara com que o sistema trave.

Existe alguma solução para isso? como bloquear a tecla enter quando o usuário teclar pela segunda vez enquanto ja estiver aberta? ou outra solução?

Pressionar Enter no campo "Pontuação Média":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dialog:

```
public async Task mensagemSimples(TextBox text, string titulo, string mensagem)
{
    var metroWindow = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow);
    await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync(titulo, mensagem);
    text.Focus();
    text.SelectAll();
}
```

Quando eu chamo ela:

```
private async void textRespPontuacaoMed_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            int min = Convert.ToInt32(textRespPontuacaoMin.Text);
            int med = Convert.ToInt32(textRespPontuacaoMed.Text);

            if (med < min)
            {
                await mensagemSimples(textRespPontuacaoMed, "Atenção", "Pontuação Média deve ser maior que a Pontuação Mínima");
                e.Handled = false;
            }else
                textRespPontuacaoMax.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Eu só esperaria o usuário interagir e depois trocaria o focus.

```
private async void textRespPontuacaoMed_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        int min = Convert.ToInt32(textRespPontuacaoMin.Text);
        int med = Convert.ToInt32(textRespPontuacaoMed.Text);

        if (med < min)
        {
            await mensagemSimples(textRespPontuacaoMed, "Atenção", "Pontuação Média deve ser maior que a Pontuação Mínima");
            text.Focus();
            text.SelectAll();
            e.Handled = false;
        }else
            textRespPontuacaoMax.Focus();
    }
}

  public async Task mensagemSimples(TextBox text, string titulo, string mensagem)
{
    var metroWindow = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow);
    await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync(titulo, mensagem);

}
```